# Is there a way to screen record or save video that is being played in a browser on my laptop?

Tags: audio, video, recording, screen-recorder

I am curious about this. I enrolled for an online course, and now the course is almost getting over. They have some video classes that I would like to save for future reference since they say that the references would only be available for 3 months after the course is over. I found that NO video download software was able to download this. I was still thinking that I could use a screen recorder to record the video while playing but to my surprise, the video is just a black screen (though audio plays).

So my question is - how do they do it such that even screen recorders cannot record the video I am playing in my browser? This is very surprising to me. And also, is there any software that anyone knows that has a chance of recording videos played in my browser?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-record-the-screen-on-your-windows-pc-or-mac

Comment: It is done the same way as Blue Ray and DRM protected players such as Netflix do it. The video is only decoded by the graphics card and is only "applied" to the display at the point where it is going to the display, not before. That way you cannot simply copy the screen buffers the way your screen recorder does. You *might* be able to use an external capture device, but the "good" ones might not like dealing with DRM enabled video streams.

Comment: Also, you can set up a video camera to record the screen. Expect reflections, sync issues (e.g., faint flickering) and other imperfections.

Comment: You said that you weren't able to find any software to download the video - can you tell me what kind of software you have already tried and/or what website this video is on?